# Asp.Net 6 MvcOption OurputFormatters.RemoveAll can't be inferred

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mongodb

I just started a test project with Asp.net 5, In the project.json file, I removed frameworks of dnxcore stuff because I am trying to play with MongoDB most recent C# driver. In my startup.cs, I have the following code:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
    services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
            options.OutputFormatters.RemoveAll(formatter =>
           formatter.Instance is   XmlDataContractSerializerOutputFormatter));
}
```

But the compiler is not happy. It shows error: the type arguments of ModelStateDictionaryExtensions.RemoveAll can't be inferred from the usage. However, the above code was used by lots of blogs and examples. Can someone tell me what I missed?

Comment: Have you added all dependencies?

Comment: there is no suggestions which dependency I have to add. I have    using Microsoft.AspNet.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ModelBinding;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection; Not sure why Return not working, sorry for the mess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as you know ASP.net MVC is going under major refresh so stuff is keep changing.

You can remove `XmlDataContractSerializerOutputFormatter` using following snipppet.

```
services.Configure<MvcOptions>(option =>
{
    option.OutputFormatters.RemoveType<XmlDataContractSerializerOutputFormatter>();
});
```

Make sure to include following dependency in your 'project.json'

```
"Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Formatters.Xml": "6.0.0-rc1-final"
```

Also don't forget to include reference it in your Startup.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Formatters;
```